# No-browser Google Maps app intent

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to open native Google Maps app when clicking a link, so I did this:

```
String urlAddress = "http://maps.google.com/maps?q="+ mylat +"," + mylon +"("+ markertitle + ")&iwloc=A&hl=en";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(urlAddress));
startActivity(intent);
```

But this just opens the url in the native browser. How can I force it to open Maps app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with:

```
String urlAddress = "http://maps.google.com/maps?q="+ mylat +"," + mylon +"("+ markertitle + ")&iwloc=A&hl=en";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(urlAddress));
intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Should I declare it in the manifest or something? And how? Cause it gives me this error:
`09-03 22:35:30.062: E/AndroidRuntime(4140): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.google.android.apps.maps/com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?`

Comment: That means that the device doesn't have the GoogleMaps application installed, you can catch the ActivityNotFoundException to avoid the crash.

Comment: Are you sure that your device has google maps installed? @user3673449

Comment: That was it, I took it for granted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String urlAddress = "http://maps.google.com/maps?q="+ mylat +"," + mylon +"("+ markertitle + ")&iwloc=A&hl=en";
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
Uri.parse(urlAddress));
startActivity(intent);
```